# Gnuplot - plotting label with different lines in hypertext

Tags: plot, label, gnuplot

Having the following text file

```
0  0  net0 aaaa bbbb cccc
1  1  net1 zzz
2  2  net2 xxx
3  3  net3 yyy
4  5  net4 ttt 0 0
5  5  net5
```

I need to plot all points described by the first two columns as x,y coordinates and anchoring the informations reported in the following columns (say 3:6) at each point.These info have to be plot separated by newlines, e.g. the point in (0,0) should report (when mouse over it)

```
net0
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

The script I'm using is the following but it works only with three columns

```
set terminal canvas enhanced mousing
set termoption enhanced
set label at 0,0 "Origin"
set title 'mouse over points'
plot 'test.txt' using 1:2:3 with labels hypertext point pt 7 ps var lc rgb "black"
```

It seems that the datafile modifier **using** works only with three entries.
Any help?

Comment: You can use some other program to add "..." around the name string. Then your commands will work to get the labels, but not as a column, only as a row.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add some different field separator, like commas, and achieve the same result with `set datafile separator ','`

Comment: I have also tried to add the field separator but I always get the labels as a row and not as column. When the third column is very long the text is not well displayed and not much readable. That's why I was asking for some workaround to get it as column. Do you know any other program which can easily plot that datafile in the way I described ?

Comment: No I don't, but it must be doable with gnuplot. Maybe using the `word()` function, the `replot` command the `do for` loop, the `system('command')`, and so on. Or maybe conversly, making a bash script that creates a large gnuplot-readable argument string from the data file and pipe it like `echo "hugeString" | gnuplot -p` from the script. I am regularly using a similar construct to plot multiple files with varying arguments from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that your text is not surrounded by `""`. Nevertheless, you can handle your issue with gnuplot without any external tool.

You didn't specify whether your data columns are separated by TAB or by space.
In the following, I assume that they are separated by single space (code needs to be adapted accordingly if not).

Procedure:

1. Read the data as full line by setting `set datafile separator "\n"`
2. extract the numbers with `word()`
3. take the rest of the line as your label text
4. replace spaces by `'\n'`

Code:

```
### Hypertext with columns
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0 0 net0 aaaa bbbb cccc
1 1 net1 zzz
2 2 net2 xxx
3 3 net3 yyy
4 5 net4 ttt 0 0
5 5 net5
EOD

# replace function
# replaces string s1 by string s2 in string s
Replace(s,s1,s2) = (RP_s="", RP_n=1, (sum[RP_i=1:strlen(s)] \
    ((s[RP_n:RP_n+strlen(s1)-1] eq s1 ? (RP_s=RP_s.s2, RP_n=RP_n+strlen(s1)) : \
    (RP_s=RP_s.s[RP_n:RP_n], RP_n=RP_n+1)), 0)), RP_s)

set datafile separator "\n"
GetNumber(n) = real(word(strcol(1),n))
GetText(s) = (s[strstrt(s," ")+1:])[strstrt(s[strstrt(s," ")+1:]," ")+1:]
TextToColumn(s) = Replace(GetText(s),' ','\n')

plot $Data u (GetNumber(1)):(GetNumber(2)):(TextToColumn(strcol(1))) w labels hypertext \
    point pt 7 ps 3 lc rgb "red" notitle
### end of code
```

Result:

[image]